# Why Pandas Data frame convert the SQL column names to upper case?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple SQL query That I am converting to a pandas data frame. Below is the code for that:

```
sql = f"""SELECT 
          OLD, OLV, Print, Search, TV 
          FROM decomposition"""
self.cursor.execute(sql)
df = self.cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
print(df)
```

The data frame columns names I expect to match the same(upper/lower) case I sent in SQL query as shown below:

```
     OLD   OLV  Print  Search     TV
0   82.5  82.5   55.0   110.0  220.0
1   82.5  82.5   55.0   110.0  220.0
```

but when I receive the data frame I see all the column names are changed to uppercase as shown below:

```
      OLD   OLV  PRINT  SEARCH     TV
0   82.5  82.5   55.0   110.0  220.0
1   82.5  82.5   55.0   110.0  220.0
```

How can I avoid this pandas data frame behavior?

I have one more scenario, where the names of the columns are not known to us. For example the below code:

```
       #getting columns
       sql = f"""SELECT distinct(MEDIACHANNEL) as columns
                  FROM Mediachannels
                  WHERE brand = '{brand}'
                  ORDER by MEDIACHANNEL"""

        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        df = self.cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
        columns_list = df["COLUMNS"].tolist()
        columns_list = list(map(str.upper, columns_list))
   
        #converting list of columns into string
        columns = ", ".join(columns_list)

        #calling the SQL query with columns as variable
        sql = f"""SELECT 
          {columns} 
          FROM decomposition"""
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        df = self.cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
        print(df)
```

In this scenario, I cant manually update the column names as I am not aware of column names as well. Hence what should I do in this scenario?

Comment: Your OS and DB name?

Comment: OS: Windows 10,  DB: snowflake